# How to print OpenCL warnings

Tags: c++, opencl, nvidia

I made a C++ program with opencl c++ bindings. It is running well on my nvidia gpu, however when using oclgrind for debugging, I get the message `6 warnings generated`. I tried using `program.getBuildInfo` and build flags -w and -Werror, but  the warnings don't show up. Using --log with oclgrind results in an empty log.

Is there any way to show those warnings? I also don't know if the warnings are generated from OpenCL or oclgrind.

Comment: Debugging OpenCL programs can be tough. What I usually do is make a function which I can call with the response code from the API calls which does nothing if the code is zero, and prints the appropriate error otherwise before aborting. There are typically be a lot of API calls in a program so the temptation can be to avoid proper error handling and reporting but I've found using such a function really helps.

Answer (score 0):

One method I've found to get that kind of warning text is to make an error in your OpenCL C code on purpose, and then `clGetProgramBuildInfo` will return a text with both warnings and errors.

May sound weird but it is the only method I use, since other intuitive approaches failed.

Here is sample output I've get using this method:

```
buildLog:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
<kernel>:75:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function                                                                                                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
<kernel>:147:66: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nh0'
```

To show a warning I've introduced undeclared identifier into OpenCL C code.